# Create object of the last child

Tags: c#

Below is my class structure if want to assign value to test property then I am creating an object for `Class1`, `Class2` and `Class3`, is there any other way to do this

```
public Class Class1 { public Class2 class2{get;set;} }

public Class Class2 { public Class3 class3{get;set;} }

public Class Class3 { public string test{get;set;} }
```

I am doing like this =

```
new Class1{ = new Class2{ = new Class3{ test = "xxx" } } }
```

Comment: The code you've posted isn't valid C#, starting from the invalid `Class` (c.f. `class`) declarations.

Comment: What do you mean "any other way"? What is wrong with the way you are doing it?

Answer (score 4):

Simply: no, for classes like

```cs
public class Class1 { public Class2 class2 { get; set; } }
public class Class2 { public Class3 class3 { get; set; } }
public class Class3 { public string test { get; set; } }
```

the most succinct construction is

```cs
var inst = new Class1 {
  class2 = new Class2 {
    class3 = new Class3 { 
      test = "xxx"
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "succinct", but certainly clearer. Also, there are other ways to do it, but all require more complex code. For example, initialise all the child objects in constructors.